# ngx-twitter-timeline angular binding data property

Tags: angular, twitter

I am trying to programatically set the data property of ngx-twitter-timeline and I can't figure it out.

```
<ngx-twitter-timeline 
    [data]="{sourceType: 'url',
             url: 'https://twitter.com/twitterdev'}"
    [opts]="{tweetLimit: 5}">
</ngx-twitter-timeline>
```

I have a field url which is set correctly (checked by console logging it) in my component and I have tried the following but none work

```
    [data]= {{url}}
    [data]= url
    [data]= "url"
```

The example on npmjs only shows a hard coded [example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-twitter-timeline)

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

My Solution

```
<div *ngIf="undefined === name">Loading...</div>
<div *ngIf="'jeffgerstmann' === name">
  jeff ngx
  <ngx-twitter-timeline [data]="{sourceType: 'url', url: 'https://twitter.com/jeffgerstmann'}" [opts]="{tweetLimit: 5}"></ngx-twitter-timeline>
</div>
<div *ngIf="'alex_navarro' === name">
    alex ngx
    <ngx-twitter-timeline [data]="{sourceType: 'url', url: 'https://twitter.com/alex_navarro'}" [opts]="{tweetLimit: 5}"></ngx-twitter-timeline>
  </div>
```